# C# method parameter syntax - what does this mean?

Tags: c#, syntax, parameters

Once I know what this means, there's probably a better way of expressing this question, but I don't know where to start.

Here's the Read method for a StreamReader:

```
public override int Read([In, Out] char[] buffer, int index, int count) { ... }
```

That "In, Out" bit - what is it for, what does it do, what's it called?

Comment: I don't get the purpose of them in this context. Aren't they just used for p/invoke and marshalling? So why are they on a normal overriding method?

Answer (score 4):

> That "In, Out" bit - what is it for, what does it do, what's it called?

They are *[parameter attributes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z0w1kczw.aspx)*.

In this case [`System.Runtime.InteropServices.InAttribute`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.inattribute.aspx) and [`System.Runtime.InteropServices.OutAttribute`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.outattribute.aspx) which are used for interop with code outside the .NET runtime.

Comment: Thank you. It would be worth changing the name of the question to make it more useful to people I think - any suggestions? (The Hokey-Cokey modifier springs to mind...)